# Android WebView evaluateJavascript, how safe?

Tags: android, security, webview

I have to send some messages to Web through my WebView.
I've found approach like this:

> To send data from native layer to Webview. Create a function in
> JavaScript to receive data in Html. Which will update inputField with
> the value received.

```
function updateFromNative(message){
       document.getElementById("inputField").value = message;
  }
<input id="inputField" style="height:50px;width:300px;font-size:20pt;" type="text" value="">
```

> Now from native layer, we can access this function by the following.

```
private fun sendDataToWebView(){
    mWebViewComponent.evaluateJavascript(
        "javascript: " + "updateFromNative(\"" + mEditText.text +  
                                                       "\")",null)
    }
```

It's work for me quite well. But I'm worried about security of this method.
Can somebody this way to use this way to still app data or any other vulnerabilities.

I would be happy if somebody take me some information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your scenario, if you use it to send/receive important data, this way is unsafe because hackers can see your data clearly and it can edit it. also, you can RSA encryption layer for communication